# Result of element is changing during getting it by script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried to get data with JavaScript:

```
<a href="/product/23" id="link_Page">The Text </a>

var link = document.getElementById('link_Page')
var text=link.innerHTML;
var href=link.href;
```

I expect to see:
"`/product/23`" and "`The Text` "

But result is:
"`http://localhost:60790/product/23`" and "`The Text&nbsp;`"

Note: on jsfiddle.js I tested and result of text(not link) was fine. couldn't understand why it's gives me '`&nbsp;`'
https://jsfiddle.net/mahma/ocwnufqb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: on jsfiddle.js I tested and result of text(not link) was fine*

`.href` will return the full URL of the linked resource, to get the exact value of the *href* attribute try using [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link_Page')
var text=link.innerHTML;
var href=link.getAttribute('href');
console.log(text);
console.log(href);
```

```html
<a href="/product/23" id="link_Page">The Text </a>
```

Comment: Thank you, for the link it works. How about text value. is there anything like .getAttribute('value') for the value?

Comment: @مهدینبوی, actually I am not sure how and where you are getting that, though you can try using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is the space character in HTML. You have a space character in the end of the `a` tag's text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can do what you want.

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link_Page')
var text = link.innerText;
var href = link.getAttribute('href');

console.log(text, href);
```

```html
<a href="/product/23" id="link_Page">The Text </a>
```